# Turn axes off for all subplots of a figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating a large array of subplots and I want to turn off axes for all the subplots.
Currently I am achieving this by

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(7, len(clusters))
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, top=1.0, bottom=0.5, left=0, right=1.0)

for x in ax.ravel():
    x.axis("off")
```

but looping over the subplots to turn of the axes individually is ugly.
Is there a way to tell `subplots` to turn od axes at creation time
or some setting on `Figure` or `pyplot` that turns axes off globally.
`pyplot.axis('off')` turns off axes just on the last subplot.

Comment: Why is it ugly?  

You can always hide it in a function `remove_numbers = lambda ax: [x.axis('off') for x in ax.ravel()]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree [with @tcaswell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34686414/turn-axes-off-for-all-subplots-of-a-figure#comment57122492_34686414) that you should probably just use what you're already using. Another option to use it as a function is to use [`numpy.vectorize()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots(7, len(clusters))
np.vectorize(lambda ax:ax.axis('off'))(ax)
```

or, if you need to invoke it multiple times, by assigning the `vectorize`d function to a variable:

```
axoff_fun = np.vectorize(lambda ax:ax.axis('off'))
# ... stuff here ...
fig, ax = plt.subplots(7, len(clusters))
axoff_fun(ax)
```

Again, note that this is the same thing that @tcaswell suggested, in a fancier setting (only slower, probably). And it's essentially the same thing you're using now.

---

However, if you insist on doing it some other way (i.e. you are a special kind of lazy), you can set [`matplotlib.rcParams`](http://matplotlib.org/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rc) once, and then every subsequent axes will automatically be `off`. There's probably an easier way to emulate `axis('off')`, but here's how I've succeeded:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

# before
mpl.pyplot.figure()
mpl.pyplot.plot([1,3,5],[4,6,5])

# kill axis in rcParams
mpl.rc('axes.spines',top=False,bottom=False,left=False,right=False);
mpl.rc('axes',facecolor=(1,1,1,0),edgecolor=(1,1,1,0));
mpl.rc(('xtick','ytick'),color=(1,1,1,0));

# after
mpl.pyplot.figure()
mpl.pyplot.plot([1,3,5],[4,6,5])
```

Result before/after:

[image: before rcparams][image: after rcparams]

Hopefully there aren't any surprises which I forgot to override, but that would become clear quite quickly in an actual application anyway.